# MergeShapes gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes

I try to merge two polygon shapes in QGIS 2.18.4 with the MergeShapes plugin.

The error message shown below is what I get in return.
Does anyone know a solution?

I want to make one table out of two with different fields.
I want QGIS to put all different fields on a row, and combine the fields that are equal in both tables.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rob/.qgis2/python/plugins\mergeshapes\mergeshapesdialog.py", line 87, in inputFile
    if files.isEmpty() or encoding is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'

Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.4 Las Palmas, 59c1d21

Comment: Not sure about the plugin (perhaps you have non-geometric features) but have you tried the **Merge vector layers** tool from `Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge vector layers`?

Comment: I just tried, but it´s not working either... It says: "global name 'dataobjects' is not defined See log for more details"

Comment: In MMQGIS - Combine I found another merge-option, but that also gives a python error... But thanks for the quick reaction!

Comment: No problem but you should probably examine your shapefiles to see if they contain any errors :)

Comment: Thanks! But they appear normal in QGIS and I can work with them without problems, except merging... Wouldn't know how to check on errors, but will have a thorough look :)

Comment: A simple but effective tool is `Check validity` from the _Processing Toolbox_ =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56997/discussion-between-rob-and-joseph).